# No results retrieving document by UUID in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I am trying to retrieve a document from MongoDB. The document has the field "ownerId" that contain a binary UUID. Using the Mongo console if I launch the command

```
db.dataset.find({ownerId: BinData(3,"ZQ6EAOKbQdSnFkRmVUUAAA==")}).pretty()
```

it returns:

```
{
    "_id" : BinData(3,"VQ6EAOKbQdSnFkRmVUUAAA=="),
    "name" : "Twitter",
    "objectType" : "Tweet",
    "ownerId" : BinData(3,"ZQ6EAOKbQdSnFkRmVUUAAA==")
}
```

When I try to retrieve the document from my node.js program, it fails and does not return any document.

My program is:

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');

var db = mongo.db("mongodb://192.168.1.100:27017/test", {native_parser:true});

function HexToBase64(g) {

   ...
}

var uuidstr = "650e8400e29b41d4a716446655450000";
console.info(uuidstr);
base64str = HexToBase64(uuidstr);
console.info(base64str);

db.collection('dataset').find( { ownerId:new mongo.Binary(base64str, 4) } ).toArray(function (err, items) {

    if(err) {
        var msg = "Error getting 'dataset' objects from database.";
        console.info(msg + " " + err);
        return;
    }

    console.info("OK");
    console.info(items);
});
```

The output is:

```
650e8400e29b41d4a716446655450000
ZQ6EAOKbQdSnFkRmVUUAAA==
OK
[]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, since you're going to query the collection by OwnerId, I'd suggest to create an index there. You can achieve that in mongoskin easily enough:

```
// Create and index by ownerId
db.collection('dataset').ensureIndex([['ownerId', 1]], true, function(err, res) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

Once you've done that, you can now do things like this:

```
db.collection('dataset').findOne({ ownerId: 'some-uuid' }, callback);
```

Further, if it's the ObjectId type you're after, I'd recommend you use the provided helper (see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24979325/992453)) to achieve that:

```
var ownerId = mongoskin.ObjectID(uuidstr);
```

Otherwise, I'd go with a different approach, [perhaps using `node-uuid`](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid) :

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var ownerId = uuid.v4();
db.collection('dataset').findOne({ ownerId: ownerId }, callback);
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of creating an index. I've already done it. 'ownerId' should not be an ObjectID, it is an UUID that I already know. On the other hand, I think I misunderstand your suggestion to use node-uuid. I don't want to generate a new UUID. I want to get an existing document which I already know the ownerId.